# Is the multiplication of two irreducible polynomials in a finite field a separable polynomial in that finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I already know that if a polynomial is irreducible in a finite field then it will be separable if it does not contain powers of X raised to the characteristic of the finite field

Comment: Are the polynomials supposed to be distinct?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to specify that

Comment: $fg$ is separable (no double root) iff $f,g$ are separable and have no root in common

Comment: Is it possible that two different irreducible polynomials have the same root in finite extensions of these? and therefore, the multiplication of these is not separable?

Comment: @David: no. That would mean that the polynomials $p,q\in k[X]$ say had a non trivial hcf in $K[X]$, with $k\subset K$. We can compute the hcf of $p,q$ in $K[X]$ by the extended euclidean algorithm. But of course that algorithm just uses coefficients which are combinations of the coefficients of $p,q$, so in fact the calculation is also a calculation of the hcf of $p,q$ in $k[X]$ - which we know is just $1$.